# Cordova orientation change

Tags: javascript, cordova, orientation, device

Good day brave cordova developers!
The main question is how to detect that corientation change is ended and window is redrawn?

I used 250ms time delay, but i'm afraid that on some slower devices this woud be not anough.

```
var app = {

    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
      init_video();
      window.addEventListener('orientationchange', init_video);
    },
};

var init_video = function(){
    //insert time out to let window to redraw
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('oriantation:'+window.orientation+'\nwidth: ' + window.outerWidth + '\nheight: '+ window.outerHeight);
    }, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can chceck this in css with media queries like [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/)

Comment: thanks for good resource, but i need thie event to add additional js-based behavior, my fault i didn't metion it before